# getType() method of com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Paragraph returning BREAK

Tags: aem

Why does `getType()` method of `com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Paragraph` returns BREAK in some cases and NORMAL in some?

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 4 Paragraph types NORMAL, START, BREAK and END.

The getType() returns **NORMAL**, if the resource is the normal **parsys**(for e.g. foundation/components/parsys).

The **START, BREAK** and **END** are returned if the resource is the start, break or end of the **column control**. In case you have used column control, you can observe that there are 3 different nodes that are created under your content (colctrl, col_break and col_end), where colctrl is the start of your column control component, col_break - the breakpoint for the first column(or n<sup>th</sup> column) and the starting point for the next column, and col_end specifies the end of the column control component. Thus, START, BREAK or END is returned based on the type of the resource.

[image: Column Control as seen in the content].